# CryptoJS AES encryption seems to ignore IV value

Tags: javascript, typescript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I stumbled upon the problem that the IV value that you pass to `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` function seems to be ignored. Following code:

```js
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

const text = "This is secret text!";
const key = "abc";
const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(2);

const encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key, { iv }).toString();
console.log(encryptedText);
const decryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedText, key, { iv: 'whatever' }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log(decryptedText);
```

Produces following output:

```
U2FsdGVkX1//3KxGM2FnVV4qR5KmWBxP/xyI1+YITvdQeXqrUBH7spIvi/Ny+7S2
This is secret text!
```

So it seems the function is able to decrypt the text no matter what IV value you are passing to the function.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify *any* IV in your code when encrypting and decrypting, because the IV is simply not used. Why is that?
Depending on the type of the key material, CryptoJS uses a key (if a WordArray is passed) or a password (if a string is passed). You pass a string, so the key material is interpreted as password (which is why `key` should better be called `password`). In this case, CryptoJS uses a key derivation function (`EVP_BytesToKey()`) to derive the key and the IV. The *explicitly* passed IV is **completely ignored**. This applies to both encryption and decryption. Therefore, if a password is applied, no IV should be used (and the one in the code should be removed).
The derived key and IV can be picked from the `CipherParams` object returned by `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt()` (s. [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output)): The key can be read from the property `key`, the IV from the property `iv` and the ciphertext from the property `ciphertext`, s. [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output).

When you pass a key instead of a password, you must also pass an IV (otherwise an error message is displayed). If you specify a wrong IV during decryption, this will result in a corrupted first block for CBC (the default mode). The details are described in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75466558/9014097).
If you want to check this, you should use a Latin1 decoding (or hex encoding) instead of a UTF-8 decoding for the decrypted data, because the corrupted data is generally not Utf-8 compatible (and CryptoJS will display an error message).
Note that short plaintexts with a ciphertext of only one block in size will generally corrupt the padding, which in turn corrupts the data during unpadding, making the data non-displayable. However, it is possible to display the *padded* data by disabling the default PKCS#7 padding: `padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding`).

The following code shows encryption/decryption with a password (1), with a key and IV (2) and the corruption of the first block for CBC when decrypting with a wrong IV (3):

```js
var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

// (1) Encryption/Decryption using a password (key and IV implicitly derived via EVP_BytesToKey)
var password = "abc"; // This is a password, not a key!
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
var encryptedOpenSSLB64 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, password, {iv: iv}).toString(); // iv ignored (since derived via key derivation) and should be removed!
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedOpenSSLB64, password, {iv: iv}); // iv ignored (since derived via key derivation) and should be removed!
console.log(encryptedOpenSSLB64);
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

// (2) Encryption/Decryption using a key and an IV
var key = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(32);
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
var ciphertextB64 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key, {iv : iv}).toString(); // iv required!
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertextB64, key, {iv : iv}); // iv required!
console.log(ciphertextB64);
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

// (3) Corruption of the first block for CBC, if a wrong IV is applied during decryption
var wrongIv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertextB64, key, {iv : wrongIv}); // wrong IV corrupts first block for CBC
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

---

For completeness: In your code the `CipherParams` object is converted to the Base64 encoded OpenSSL format with `toString()`. The OpenSSL format consists of the ASCII encoding of `Salted__` followed by an 8 bytes salt and the actual ciphertext. Because of the constant prefix `Salted__` the Base64 encoded data always starts with `U2FsdGVkX1` (like your ciphertext).
The random salt is generated during encryption. Based on salt and password, the key derivation function is used to derive key and IV. In order to be able to reconstruct key and IV during decryption, the salt is required. The salt is not secret, so it is usually concatenated with the ciphertext (as in the OpenSSL format described above). The salt is also contained in the `salt` property of the `CipherParams` object.
If no password but a key is applied, there is no salt and `toString()` returns only the Base64 encoding of the `ciphertext` property. This is also illustrated in the above code snippet.
`CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()` requires a `CipherParams` object (s. [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input)). Alternatively (as in your code) the Base64 encoding created with `toString()` can be passed. This is implicitly converted into a `CipherParams` object.

Answer (score 1):

CryptoJS is using AES-CBC. CBC is not an authenticated mode of operation, so it doesn't offer message integrity / authenticity. CBC only offers confidentiality, and only that while it is used correctly and doesn't allow for, for instance, padding oracle attacks.

Actually, the IV in CBC mode only changes the first block of plaintext during decryption, and only those bytes where the IV differs. So all the rest of the blocks simply decrypt as you'd expect. This is because the IV is only the *initialization vector*. The other "vectors" that are XOR'ed with the plaintext before AES block encryption are the previous blocks of ciphertext. Probably best to have a look at the [Wikipedia page explaining the modes of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)).

---

Beware that the line:

```
const encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key, { iv }).toString();
```

is not correct: `iv` should be a named field:

```
const encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key, { iv: iv }).toString();
```

It's not entirely clear if this is deliberate or not from the rest of the context in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but what is the point of using IV then, if you can decode the data with just the key?

Comment: IND-CPA, indistinguishability when using chosen plaintext. If this isn't provided then you can distinguish parts of the ciphertext if you know the plaintext of another encryption. IND-CPA is stronger, but imagine encrypting a message containing "Yes" twice. Then the IV is used to make sure the messages encrypt to different ciphertext. Say that you decide to attack an army when receiving a "Yes". The attack was unsuccessful and you decide to attack on the next "Yes". The opposing army knew you attacked on the previous yes, and now they see the same ciphertext...